# Pagespeed score is different from gtmetrix -also different questions about pagespeed score

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, gtmetrix

My pagespeed score is different on gtmetrix.com and google pagespeed.The difference is huge.

Gtmetrix.com says:

PageSpeed Score
(99%) 
YSlow Score
(94%)

Google pagespeed says:

53 for mobile , 88  for desktop

my website link: http://www.hekim2.deniz-tasarim.site/

Why these scores are different so huge?

How can I raise google pagespeed score?

---

I changed body background color to current color from default white, then google pagespeed score raised.So, if I use loading gif, can I raise google pagespeed score?

Does else technique exist to raise pagespeed score?

Comment: try and limit your questions to just one thing at a time, at the moment this question is too broad for us to answer as you asked 4 different questions. Have a quick read of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask good questions that will get answered here. FYI - I tried to test your site but it appears you are working on it and things are broken so it got 1 / 100 and there were about 20 console errors.

Answer (score 0):

> Why these scores are different so huge?

GTMetrix **emulates** Google Pagespeed Insights & ySlow engine.
They used to be 100% similar in many cases but lately Lighthouse takes into account the Lab Data as well.

**First Contentful Paint**, **First meaningful paint** etc etc.
These factors play a huge role on mobile devices.

GTMetrix only takes account of pageload and DocumentLoaded state.

Also, GTMetrix is having limited locations on which you can check your website.

Therefore, you see those differences.

In my humble opinion pagespeed insights is the most accurate tool.

> How can I raise google pagespeed score?

Well, there are a lot of things you can still do to increase pagespeed score.

Personally I'd check the Images first. 
take a look at here for example:
https://www.imghaste.com/pagespeed/958283cc-b2d6-47d2-a569-fc23c62604d1

After having those images Well optimized, run the the report again.

**Next thing you can do** is add a lazy load mechanism, there are unlimited plugins that offer lazy load functionalities.